# How to instal yum on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.7 (Santiago)?

Tags: rhel, package-management, python, yum

I am trying to install some packages using yum but yum is not installed

`$ yum install`

```
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   No module named yum

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.7.10 (default, Jun 12 2015, 16:19:57) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to 
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

Comment: Do you have `dnf` ?

Comment: @icarus - No,I don't

Answer (score 1):

You’ve installed a version of python that doesn’t come with RHEL 6. The version in RHEL 6 is version 2.6.6.

Because you are using a non-RHEL python, it’s missing the yum module. If you just changed the /usr/bin/python to a symlink to some other python install, I suggest fixing it and trying again.

If you replaced the packaged python, you need to reinstall the python package from RHEL. I suggest you grab the lates rhel6 install dvd iso and install from there using the rpm command.

At this point though, I’d consider calling it a loss and just back up the data and install rhel7 or rhel8 and recreate your services. Rhel6 support ends in November.